# R Ggplot ggiraph - Interactive line show value between two points

Tags: r, ggplot2, linechart, interactive, ggiraph

I am trying to render an interactive plot with geom_line_interactive. As shown in the example below, geom_line_interactive just shows the first x value throughout the whole graph. Is there a way to basically display the nearest x value given in the dataset?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggiraph)
if( requireNamespace("dplyr", quietly = TRUE)){
  recent <- economics[economics$date > as.Date("2013-01-01"), ]
  gg = ggplot(recent, aes(date, unemploy)) +
    geom_step_interactive(aes(tooltip = date, data_id = date))
  x <- girafe(ggobj = gg)
  x <- girafe_options(x = x,
                      opts_hover(css = "stroke:red;") )
  if( interactive() ) print(x)
}
```

[In the picture I expected to see '2013-07' in the tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozPSL.png)

Comment: That's the expected behavior. It behaves the same way as other aesthetics (colors, fill, etc.) in ggplot2. So here you can only have one tooltip per line.

Comment: Good to know, thanks!